# Get Current folder name of selected file in Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TextBox` to search the files in main folder, it has sub-folder(s) too. I want to get the current folder name of selected item in `ListBox`, to be displayed in another `ListBox`.

How do I do this?

My latest effort:

Here is my full coding!!

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\guest\Desktop\test\";

        listBox2.Items.Clear();

        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo sdir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\guest\Desktop\test");
        FileInfo[] files = sdir.GetFiles(textBox1.Text.ToString() + "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string search = "";

        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            search = file.Name;
            listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(search));
        }
    }
```

**Required output marked in red** refer below snap.

Filename search and get full path
[image: Filename search and get full path]

Comment: `current folder name` Do you mean the path (excluding filename)?

Comment: It looks like you have a hard-coded folder name right there in the code.  It's not really clear what the problem is.  What is the selected item?  What actually populates the listbox?

Comment: Educated guess. I think you are trying to display sub folders of the selected folder in listBox2. How about `System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path)`

Comment: Either that, or `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path)` ?

Comment: `GetDirectoryName` get only blank if you have no directory information. Can you post the string value `listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you are adding to `listBox1` you are adding a `string` - which then loses the context of its original path. The solution is to instead add an `object` (e.g. `TestPath`) - which can `ToString` into the text you want **but still hold the context of its original path**.

Below may assist you towards that aim.

Add this class:

```
public class TestPath
{
    public FileInfo Original { get; private set; }

    public TestPath(FileInfo original)
    {
        Original = original;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Original.Name);
    }
}
```

Then replace:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    search = file.Name;
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(search));
}
```

with:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    var path = new TestPath(file);
    listBox1.Items.Add(path);
}
```

Then replace:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\guest\Desktop\test\";

    listBox2.Items.Clear();

    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    }
}
```

with:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox2.Items.Clear();

    var currentItem = listBox1.SelectedItem as TestPath;
    listBox2.Items.Add(currentItem.Original.FullName); // or any property
}
```

Comment: Error while debug. error-1: files does not exist  in the current context  (Form1.cs) & error-2: 'System.IO.FileSystemInfo.FullPath' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: For your reference, [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OXyEff). I am missing any thing, kindly guide me if any!!

Comment: You removed code from `textBox1_TextChanged` that I did not suggest that you remove. Please revert to your original code, then re-apply **just** the changes that I suggested.

Comment: It is working as I expected, Thank very much to complete my application